# (Unity) Реализация закадрового индикатора цели через UI (offscreen target indicator)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Ну что же, проблема довольно известная, однако где бы я не был, никто и нигде не делал подобного на UI. Ну или я плохо сёрфил WWW. В общем вот чего мы добиваемся:

[image: Примерная реализация задачи.]
.

В моём случае чёрным прямоугольником будет `Canvas` с параметром отображения `Screen Space - Overlay`, индикаторами `UI Image` а цели(враги) `GameObject`.

Ниже я оставлю способ решения этой проблемы, и поясню, почему он мне не подходит.

**Мне требуется вот такая система, но работающая на UI.**

*PS: Возможно вопрос будет глупым, но в моём возрасте по системе образования мы ещё даже не должны знать определение радиана.*

Answer (score 0):

Ну, что же, вот этот скрипт нужно положить на GameObject стрелки, которая будет указать на цель.

*Ну и собственно Sprite Render со стрелкой, которая будет отображаться
 поставить не забудьте.*

```
using UnityEngine;

public class OffScreenArrow : MonoBehaviourTFD {

//Цель, на которую будет показывать стрелка.
public Transform target;

void LateUpdate()
{
    //Если цель существует...
    if (target)
    {
        Vector3 v_diff = (target.position - GOs.Player.transform.position);
        float atan2 = Mathf.Atan2(v_diff.y, v_diff.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        //В моём случае спрайт стрелки повёрнут вверх, так что я отнял 90 градусов.
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, atan2 - 90);

        //Вычесляем нужное значение...
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, 1000);

        //и подганяем его под размеры экрана.
        Vector3 pos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);

        pos.x = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.x);
        pos.y = Mathf.Clamp01(pos.y);

        transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(pos);
    }
}
}
```

И хотя скрипт немного сыроват, но свою основную функцию он выполняет достаточно не плохо.

*Но тут всплывают серьёзный минус: `UI Image` с моим канвасом будут всегда приоритетнее чем `Sprite Render`, а значит, что интерфейс будет загораживать эту стрелку, что вообще не вариант. 
Так же не очень удобно работать с кучей таких стрелок, ведь они будут перекрывать друг-друга и отсортировать их как `UI Image` будет нельзя. Поэтому хоть этот вариант частично годится, но мне он не подходит.*